# Java 1.7, clock format not working

Tags: java, javafx, integer, datetime-format

I tried a very simple clock (and it works). But the problem is, the time i get can be:
18:7, instead of 18:07. I tried correcting with an integer test of `< 10`, but for some reason it says that it never runs. Can you tell me why it won't compare and how I can correct it? Btw, here is the code :)

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DigitalClock extends Label {

    static private String addhour;
    static private String addmin;
    static private String addmonth;
    static private String addday;

    // constructor
    public DigitalClock() {
        bindToTime();
    }

    void bindToTime() {
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0),
                new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                        Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
                        if (Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY < 10) {
                            addhour = " 0";
                        } else {
                            addhour = " ";
                        }
                        if (Calendar.MINUTE < 10) {
                            addmin = ":0";
                        } else {
                            addmin = ":";
                        }
                        if ((Calendar.MONTH + 1) < 10) {
                            addmonth = ".0";
                        } else {
                            addmonth = ".";
                        }
                        if (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH < 10) {
                            addday = ".0";
                        } else {
                            addday = ".";
                        }
                        setText(addhour + time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
                                + addmin + time.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
                                + "\n" + time.get(Calendar.YEAR)
                                +addmonth + (time.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)
                                + addday + time.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                    } // end of handle
                } // end of EventHandler
                ), // end of new KeyFrame
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1))); // end of Timeline
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
    } // end of bindToTime
} // end of class DigitalClock
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: why not use SimpleDateFormat ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Calendar.MINUTE` is just a constant in the `Calendar` class, not the number of minutes in the `time` object.

Therefore, instead of `Calendar.MINUTE < 10` you should write `time.get(Calendar.MINUTE) < 10`.

Nevertheless, I agree with Scary Wombat: try [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) first.

Comment: I haven't tried `SimpleDateFormat`  ^^""... yeah, sounds like a good idea for next time. But the `time.get(Calendar.MINUTE) < 10`  did work, none the less, so thank you, both of you :)